# AngularJS как правильно использовать $http сервис

Tags: angularjs, rest

Есть одностраничное веб-приложение написанное на простом `PHP` с использованием `JQuery` и `AJAX`. Пользователи в нем проходят авторизацию. Все делается самыми обычными методами: отправка формы на сервер, проверка логина/пароля, хранение данных в сессии. Все скрипты, к которым обращается `JQuery` содержат проверку данных сессии на то, что пользователь авторизован, ну и результат выполнения может меняться в зависимости от `ID` пользователя.

Я хочу переписать все с использованием `AngularJS`. Вопрос в том, как правильно организовать взаимодействие с сервисом `$http`. Стоит ли следовать `REST` идеологии и насколько это важно, соответствует ли философии `AngularJS`. Может стоит подумать о разработке `API` и потом к нему обращаться уже. Где хранить данные пользователя если не в сессии. В принципе, все конечно будет работать и так, но хочется сделать именно правильно. Посоветуйте в какую сторону копать, что почитать не заумного (понятным языком написанного)

UPD:
Перечитал и понял, что надо конкретизировать вопросы, а то получается фигня.

1. Если я буду просто хранить ID пользователя и хеш пароля на клиенте (в переменных $scope) и использовать их при обращении к API будет ли это корректным решением?
2. У меня есть ряд классов PHP, которые реализуют модель данных (CRUD и все такое) и "скрипты-диспетчеры" к которым я обращаюсь через JQuery (передаю данные POST-ом), они проверяют авторизацию, вызывают нужные методы в зависимости от параметров и возвращают результат (обычто HTML). Я так понимаю, что правильно будет сохранить всю модель данных и сделать другого "диспетчера", который будет разбирать запрос (метод, URL, параметры переданные) и так же вызывать в зависимотсти от ситуации нужные методы чтоб сформировать JSON ответ. Правильно? Поправьте если ошибаюсь.

Оффтоп
Че-то меня все чаще посещает мысль, что надо бросать уже ПХП и писать бэкенд на чем-нибудь нормальном

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что у вас и так правильный взгляд на предмет.

Comment: я надеюсь переписать на 2 ангуляр, первый не торт, очень медленный

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я переписал уже, заметной прибавки в скорости не видно не вооруженным взглядом, но писать стало намного приятнее, учитывая в том числе, что TypeScript.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian значит ты не писал большие приложения, ангуляр первый это просто жесть, он плодил биндинги тоннами

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев писал очень большое приложение, около миллиона строк js. Если следить за биндингами и не засирать страницу ими сотнями, то вполне все шустренько бегает.

Comment: К оффтопу - на пхп бекенд (если вы неплохо знаете php) вполне себе нормальное решение, не забивайте голову.

Comment: Авторизуйте пользователя - отправьте на сервер введенный логин/пароль, получите от сервера токен (рандомную строку), используйте его в последующих запросах (можно в заголовок http засунуть, можно в тело json запроса, как вам удобно). Если нужно, чтобы при обновлении страницы авторизация не слетала - сохраняйте в localstorage/куки токен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS не противоречит REST.

Скрипты к которым у вас обращается JQuery, если они возвращают JSON или XML по сути уже являются API, пусть и не REST.

Можно авторизацию реализовать на API, в сессии она не храниться она использует токен, для этого вам нужно изучить OAUTH 2.0, используя её вы так же сможете прикрутить авторизацию ВК, Facebook для своего проекта.

UPD: ответы на UPD вопроса.

У нас есть 2 типа http запросов. Первый это запросы результат которых даёт html странички, Второй тип это api запросы, результат будет в формате json.

Авторизация. В php сессия удерживается с помощью cookie или если cookie не работают, указывают session_id в запросе. Тот же принцип можно использовать для api запросов. При формировании api запроса в сервисе angular, добавляем в запрос значения cookie (если они не добавляются автоматически) или если не работают cookie добавляем session_id. Так проверка прав api запроса не будет отличаться от проверки обычных html запросов и не нужно создавать дополнительную систему авторизации.

Какие цели API?

Если цель создать поставщика данных для сторонних сервисов, то желательно использовать стандарты и документирование API, и авторизацию через OAUTH.

Если цель улучшить отклик интерфейса, то используем авторизацию такую как я описал выше, REST следовать не обязательно, т.к. вы являетесь потребителем своего api. Но что бы не запутаться лучше всё таки использовать REST. Http delete и put запросы не должны смущать их не сложно обрабатывать.

Что бы диспетчеру проще было различать html и api запросы, реализуйте backend так, что бы перед API запросами был префикс /api/

Comment: Да, то что скрипты и есть API понятно, весь вопрос теперь в том как это сделать правильно.

Про OAUTH 2.0 я читал, но не уверен, что стоит городить огород

Вообще я понял, что надо конкретизировать вопросы

Comment: UPD Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь стало яснее. Цель API - работать с ним самому. Но хочется все-же сделать по правилам чтобы во-первых получить хороший опыт, а во-вторых чтоб было приятнее и проще работать над фронтендом